# Is there free Windows software that can be used with a NEC MDSVSENSOR3 colorimeter?

Tags: software-recommendation, colorimeter

I'm looking to calibrate one of my screens. I purchased a [NEC MDSVSENSOR3](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/827959-REG/NEC_MDSVSENSOR3_SpectraSensor_Pro_Color_Calibration.html) a while back. It still works just fine, but I'm not sure if it came with the NEC SpectraViewII software; if it did, I don't have the license key anymore.

I'd rather not go out and purchase a new colorimeter, **what free software is out there that can be used with my model colorimeter?**  I'm running Windows 7 Pro.  I've used [basICColor display 5](http://www.basiccolor.de/basiccolor-display-5-en/) but the free trial has expired and I only calibrated one of my monitors.

Thanks for your help in advance greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What OS are you running on the device for which you wish to calibrate the screen?

Comment: @MichaelClark forgot to add that part... Windows 7 Professional

Comment: The sensor comes with SpectraView and so, you can call NEC and ask for a new license, giving them your serial number perhaps. It's worth a shot at least. Alternatively, you can actually just pay for the software rather than the a new colorimeter.

Comment: Call NEC tech support. They will be able to look up your order and issue you with a replacement serial number.

Comment: @Itai Thanks for your response. I've reached out to them waiting for response.

Comment: @Gmck Thanks for your response. I've reached out to them waiting for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NEC MDSVSensor3 is the same colorimeter as the X1 i1 Display Pro. It is modified to work only on NEC wide gamut monitors. But at this point it wouldn't hurt to try using [DisplayCAL](http://displaycal.net/#about) (formerly known as dispcalGUI) that is open source and lists the X1 i1 Display Pro as compatible. From the DisplayCAL page:

> X-Rite i1 Display Pro, ColorMunki Display (since Argyll CMS 1.3.4. The HP DreamColor, NEC SpectraSensor Pro and SpectraCal C6 versions of the instrument are also reported to work)